# P/Invoke with [Out] StringBuilder / LPTSTR and multibyte chars: Garbled text?

Tags: pinvoke, stringbuilder, multibyte, lptstr

---

I'm trying to use P/Invoke to fetch a string (among other things) from an unmanaged DLL, but the string comes out garbled, no matter what I try.

I'm not a native Windows coder, so I'm unsure about the character encoding bits. The DLL is set to use "Multi-Byte Character Set", which I can't change (because that would break other projects). I'm trying to add a wrapper function to extract some data from some existing classes. The string in question currently exists as a CString, and I'm trying to copy it to an LPTSTR, hoping to get it into a managed StringBuilder.

This is what I have done that I believe is the closest to being correct (I have removed the irrelevant bits, obviously):

```
// unmanaged function
DLLEXPORT void Test(LPTSTR result)
{
  // eval->result is a CString
  _tcscpy(result, (LPCTSTR)eval->result);
}
```

---

```
// in managed code
[DllImport("Test.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern void Test([Out] StringBuilder result);
```

---

```
// using it in managed code
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
Test(result);
// contents in result garbled at this point
```

---

```
// just for comparison, this unmanaged consumer of the same function works
LPTSTR result = new TCHAR[100];
Test(result);
```

Really appreciate any tips! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

One problem  is using `CharSet.Auto`.

On an NT-based system this will assume that the result parameter in the native DLL will be using Unicode.  Change that to `CharSet.Ansi` and see if you get better results.

You also need to size the buffer of the StringBuilder that you're passing in:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(100); // problem if more than 100 characters are returned
```

Also - the native C code is using '`TCHAR`' types and macros - this means that it could be built for Unicode.  If this might happen it complicates the `CharSet` situation in the `DllImportAtribute` somewhat - especially if you don't use the `TestA()`/`TestW()` naming convention for the native export.

Answer (score 3):

Dont use out paramaeter as you are not allocating in c function

```
[DllImport("Test.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern void Test(StringBuilder result);

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(100);
Test(result);
```

This should work for you

Answer (score 0):

You didn't describe what your garbled string looks like. I suspect you are mixing up some MBCS strings and UCS-2 strings (using 2-byte wchar_ts). If every other byte is 0, then you are looking a UCS-2 string (and possibly misusing it as an MBCS string). If every other byte is *not* 0, then you are probably looking at an MBCS string (and possibly misusing it as a Unicode string).

In general, I would recommend not using `TCHAR`s (or `LPTSR`s). They use macro magic to switch between `char` (1 byte) and `wchar_t` (2 bytes), depending on whether `_UNICODE` is `#define`d. I prefer to explicit use `chat` and `wchar_t` to make the codes intent very clear. However, you will need to call the -A or -W forms of any Win32 APIs that use `TCHAR` parameters: e.g. `MessageBoxA()` or `MessageBoxW()` instead of `MessageBox()` (which is a macro that checks whether `_UNICODE` is `#define`d.

Then you should change `CharSet = CharSet.Auto` to something `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi` (if both caller and callee are using MBCS) or `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode` (if both caller and callee are using UCS-2 Unicode). But it sounds like your DLL is using MBCS, not Unicode.

[pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/) is a great wiki reference with many examples of P/Invoke function signatures for Win32 APIs: